# Understanding negative log likelihood

Tags: likelihood

I am trying to answer the following question

[image: Likelihood is given by]

[image: Show the form]

I understand that

[image: Gaussian]

So I thought I could simply substitute $y_i$ for $x_i$ in the gaussian formula and proceed from there.
However if I do this then the negative sign is the wrong way around.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be handling the sign wrong somehow

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right)^{1/2}= \frac{1}{2}\log \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi\sigma^2)$$
and
$$\log \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}}\left(\mu-y_{i}\right)^{2}\right) = -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}}\left(\mu-y_{i}\right)^{2} $$
so the loglikelihood has minus signs and the minus loglikelihood doesn't

Comment: I missed that ($\mu -y_i)^2 = (y_i-\mu)^2$